Securing a linux machine with server running applications
I have a Kubuntu 24.04 and I want to install, for development purposes applications that open ports. Specifically install docker, k8s, cassandra, mysql or kafka.
What do I need to do to make sure my installation is secure and that these ports are not exploited externally? Should I use a specific kind of firewall? Is only a firewall sufficient?

Is your system connected directly to the public Internet, without any  router and LAN?

@Kusalananda:It is meant to be running in a home environment connecting to WIFI via the router provided by ISP

Why the vote to close? Does the question need improvement? Is it off topic? Please clarify if you vote for close

If the machine is behind the firewall implemented by your IPS's router, the network that your machine is connected to should be a local private network. Opening ports on your system should open them to the private network. I don't directly see an issue with this unless you believe that the private network isn't truly private (it is shared with people in your houshold that you do not trust).

I also voted to close. The question is far too broad as it is. I advise breaking down those needs in much small areas and asking far more focused questions as you go along. You also have SE groups more focused on general security theory and practice.

@Kusalananda: there is no issue with not trusting people in my household. But I thought that if I started e.g. docker it could be accessible from the outside via the public IP that my ISP assigns to me.

@Jim The public IP surely is assigned to your router, not your computer on your private network?

@Kusalananda: What is the difference? My public IP is exposed as I don't have a VPN. If e.g. docker or MySQL opens a port for client connections, if someone uses that public IP + (docker or MySQL) port, can't they connect to my pc?

@Jim, your computer does not have a public IP; your router does. Someone accessing your public IP address would arrive at your router, not your computer.  Your router does not automatically forward requests through your private network to your computer (unless you specifically set it up to do so).

@Kusalananda: so if I start a server listening to a port X, only PCs connected to the same wifi can access it and nothing outside? How can I verify that? I.e. that the default rules from my ISP are indeed enforcing that?

There are multiple ways to secure applications that open ports.
In order from most specific to widest locus:

Configure (or program) the application to limit and/or sanitize what input it accepts
Use application configuration (if available) to authenticate connections and users and apply ACLs and limit permissions to least necessary.
Configure the application to limit what external hosts it accepts connections from.  Many applications support accepting connections only from the local machine or a specific interface as opposed to 0.0.0.0 (every interface) or the ipv6 equivalent, or filter by ip address within the application for more granularity.
Containerize applications and limit what the application can access outside of its container and possibly make part or all of the container read only to minimize damage even if the application is compromised.  Use a container system that is security focused; some container solutions do not implement much security at all and can actually weaken security.
Configure the machine's local firewall to limit what ports can be connected to externally, which can limit which ports and applications are exposed.
Secure local wireless networks and/or put them outside your local network's firewall to minimize risk from bad actors in physical proximity to your wireless networks.
Configure an external firewall (including your own and your ISP's and any others between your local network and the outside world) to limit connections to local machines from the external network.

You may wonder which of these is best, but that's really the wrong approach.  Defense in depth methodology says you should implement as many of these as practical.
Consider even if you configure application security tightly, you might miss something or a bug in the application might bypass that security, so protection at the next level will reduce that risk.  Even if you block all but local network connections on a host, another host on your network could be attacked and your host hit with a lateral attack, so firewalling the entire network limiting exposure of all hosts will reduce that risk.  Limiting ingress into the network through a limited number of highly watched and secured hosts will mitigate risks further, etc.

When you say external firewall do you mean the ISP's router/modem?

I'll clarify both points.

The ISP firewall is the one configured on the router/modem provided by my ISP?

How you label the router is really irrelevant.  There may be multiple ISP routers that you may or may not know about or have control over.  There are only three distinctions that matter here -- host local firewall, external firewall on another device you can control, and external firewall(s) you can't control.

What local firewall do you recommend? Does kubuntu come with a default one?

The firewall is built into the kernel.  Really what you want is a tool to configure that.  You can use iptables, firewalld, ufw, there may be others.  It doesn't matter which one you use, but I recommend one you can figure out how to configure correctly for your needs.
